# Need a Python script for Slack to deactivate a user

Tags: python, slack

```
import os

from slackclient import slackclient 

SLACK_TOKEN = os.eviron.get ('SLACK_TOKEN')

slack_client = SlackClient (SLACK_TOKEN)

username=raw_input("Please Type the user you would like to deactivate: ")
print "User: "

users.admin.setInactive <--- Not sure how to implement this
```

Comment: That's all I could ever want for it. Run the function then check its response. if ok = true then its been disabled, if it's false then display that it failed to disable...

Comment: OK thanks! (Im quite new to python)

Comment: we've all been in your position just play around with it. you need to provide a userID and your "legacy" token which i presume are strings. not sure about how the method parameters are set but just bash it until it works

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this API method a) needs a [legacy token](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) and b) only works on the payed version of Slack

Comment: Yeah same question just looking for extra information